# Running a javascript function several times onmouseover

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that moves a box when hovering a button. I would like the function to run over and over again every second as long as the mouse hovers over the button. I have tried loops too but I can't get this to work. I would be very thankful if you would look into this.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
#box {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;   
    background:#333366;
}
</style>

<script>
function Start() {  

setInterval(Move('box'),1000);

}

var value = 0;
function Move(element) {

    value += 50;    
    var box = document.getElementById(element);
    box.style.transition = "left 0.2s ease-in-out 0s";
    box.style.left = value+'px';    

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onmouseover="Start();">Hover to move</button>
<div id="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should describe the desired result and the actual problem you are running into or people might not give you the answer you're really looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    Move('box')
},1000);
```

You have to pass a function to setInterval. You were actually calling Move and passing its return value.

Answer (score 1):

something like this maybe?

http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/HwKb3/1/

```
var value = 0,
    timer,
    btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.onmouseover = function(){
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        //    your loop code here
        Move('box');
    }, 1000);
};

btn.onmouseout = function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
}

function Move(element) {

    value += 50;
    var box = document.getElementById(element);
    box.style.transition = "left 0.2s ease-in-out 0s";
    box.style.left = value + 'px';

}
```

Try to see jQuery, it might help you in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Nice that you showed me how to make the box stop because I realized that the box just kept on moving when mousing out of the button.

Answer (score 0):

When this line

```
setInterval(Move('box'),1000);
```

is executed, `Move('box')` is evaluated (and executed one), therefore, your argument to `setInterval` is the return value for it, that is `null`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var value = 0;
function move(element) {
    value += 50;
    var box = document.getElementById(element);
    box.style.transition = "left 0.2s ease-in-out 0s";
    box.style.left = value+'px';
    // console.log(box);
}

var button = document.getElementById("buttonID");
button.onmouseover = function() {
    this.iid = setInterval(function() {
        move("boxID");
    }, 1000);
};

button.onmouseout = function() {
    this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not very familiar with jQuery yet.